# Why is there a signedness issue when comparing uint16_t and unsigned int?

Tags: c++, integer

I have a code like this :

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    uint16_t a = 0;
    uint16_t b = 0;

    if ( a - b < 3u )
    {
        cout << "cacahuète" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it using g++ with `-Wall`, I get :

```
temp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
temp.cpp:9:13: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
    9 |  if ( a - b < 3u )
      |       ~~~~~~^~~~
```

That warning doesn't show up if I write `if ( a - b < static_cast<uint16_t>(3u) )` instead.

- So what's going on, here ? Where does the int come from?
- Can this actually result in an incorrect behavior?
- Is there a less verbose way to silence it? (or a less verbose way to write a uint16_t literal?)

Comment: What if a = 0 and b = 1 ?

Comment: Note that `-1 > 2u` in C++. This is not intuitive and the rules for mixed signed operands are very [com-](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Numeric_promotions) and [plex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions). Imho one should avoid mixing unsigned and signed integer types altogether. In your example there is no reason to not use `int16_t` instead of `uint16_t` and `3` instead of `3u`.

Comment: `if ( static_cast<unsigned>(a - b) < 3u )`

Comment: @JakobStark I mean, this is not my actual code but a minimal reproduction of the problem I'm encountering, and using uint16_t is fully legitimate in the real code. I also know that I can get around the issue in various ways, but I'm asking the question because I want to understand the language better and know what is that issue I'm getting around

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So what's going on, here ? Where does the int come from?

Integer promotion is going on here. On systems where `std::uint16_t` is smaller than `int`, it will be promoted  to `int` when used as an operand (of most binary operations).

In `a - b` both operands are promoted to `int` and the result is `int` also. You compare this signed integer to `3u` which is `unsigned int`. The signs differ, as the compiler warns you.

> That warning doesn't show up if I write `if ( a - b < static_cast<uint16_t>(3u) )` instead.

Here, the right hand operand is also promoted to `int`. Both sides of comparison are signed so there is no warning.

> Can this actually result in an incorrect behavior?

`if ( a - b < static_cast<uint16_t>(3u) )` does have different behaviour than `a - b < static_cast<uint16_t>(3u)`. If one is correct, then presumably the other is incorrect.

> Is there a less verbose way to silence it? (or a less verbose way to write a uint16_t literal?)

The correct solution depends on what behaviour you want to be correct.

---

P.S. You forgot to include the header that defines `uint16_t`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It compiles as is, but it's true I should have included cstdint here. This raises other issues, so I think I'll open another question

Comment: @Eternal No need to open. Use the search instead. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'll obviously be searching first, but I suspect I won't find the answer to what I want to ask

Comment: I didn't find what I was looking for, but I think it's because there is nothing to find. I read a bit about integer promotion but as far as I can tell when you perform an operation on two fixed-type integer you can't know anything about the resulting type except that it's at least as big as the original one, given that `int` is at least int16_t but can be pretty much any size. That would be alright if signedness was preserved, but it isn't, so the only way to go about this seems to be very careful and to perform a cast after each operation, even for a "basic" type such as `unsigned short`